# How can you set a global validation rule with FormKit

Tags: vue.js, formkit

I am creating forms with `FormKit` and using the `Schema` to build up the forms.

We need to make it so the `required` validation rule is a generic message `This field is required`, rather than `[field] is required`

Is there a way to globally update that, rather than having to pass this to every field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can change this by overriding the global config. Wherever you are registering FormKit:

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { plugin, defaultConfig } from '@formkit/vue'
import App from 'App.vue'

createApp(App).use(plugin, defaultConfig({
  messages: {
    en: {
      validation: {
        required: 'This field is required'
      }
    }
}).mount('#app')
```

This was pulled from the docs here: https://formkit.com/essentials/validation#global-validation-message

Comment: that is awesome, thanks @jpschroeder, i didn't see that when i flicked through the docs